# Using multiple schemas, using SQL views from SQL Server Reporting Services 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a database with multiple schemas that have the same data model, including some views.  When I try to create a data model using SSRS 2008, I don't see any of the views, and the table names are created with trailing numbers in their names instead of their original schemas, i.e., `dbo.MY_TABLE` and `IMPORT.MY_TABLE` become `MY TABLE` and `MY TABLE1` with no indication as to which is which.

How can I get the views to show up?  I'm not good enough with Google to figure out how to weed out the results about SQL views from the ones about SSRS views (and those that simply have the word "Views" in them.)  Also, is there a way to format the tables names so that they're more friendly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is to use Visual Studio 2008 and BIDS rather than using the Web-based tools that come with SSRS, unless someone knows of a different way.

Comment: I marked this as the answer, since nothing else came up, and this works.